# How to importe or modify dynamic css on router change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I meet a problem in my project.When I change the url or click a link,then I enter a "new page",but we know that different route match different Container Component,of course we can control our style in the component,but how to change the body or html style?

My current way to slove this is change the css in the Container-Component's `mount` and `unmount` method of one route.For example,Now I am in the `Repos` page,there are many repos,and then I click one repo,the url change and new things render by the `UserRepo`.It Looks like:

```
  /* route.js */

  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos} >
      <Route path="/repos/:repoId" component={UserRepo} />
    </Route>
   </Route>

  /* Repos.js */
  componentDidMount () {
     removeClass(document.querySelector('body'), 'cssClassName');
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
     addClass(document.querySelector('body'), 'cssClassName');
  }
```

It does work fine,but I want to ask that are there other good ways to solve this by react-router?Maybe we can add some attributes on the Route component,assuming the attribute name is "willLoadedCssObject",so we can pass something like `{body: {fontSize: '20px'}}` to the "willLoadedCssObject" attribute of Route.

So, how to process the attribute?Maybe we can append a `<style>` tag to the body or fetch some css file from server and append a `<link>` tag to the body if the willLoadedCssObject is a url.Of course these is just my thought,happy to dicuss with anyone.

Comment: Why are you changing the body styles? CSS for the body should really only be for things that are present throughout your entire site/app. If you want different styles between pages they should be attached to the container component of those routes. Otherwise you get weird situations like this where you're manually editing styles attached to the body element.

Comment: @Jayce444 For example,background-image

Comment: Again, if you want a different background image for different pages then you shouldn't have it on the body element, it should be on a container element that has the same dimensions as the body

Comment: @Jayce444 I know your meaning,but the problem is the container element that **has not** the same dimensions as the body in many situations.

Comment: @markerikson could you advise anything?Or use css in js?

Comment: Sorry nothing else I can think of. If the outermost container elements HAVE to be different then you might just have to do it via JS.

Comment: Ye,you are right.I just want react-router encapsulate the logic or implement this as a enhencer,that would help us decrease many reduplicative code.